# Ubuntu 18 and TeamViewer

Tags: teamviewer

I am using TeamViewer to remotely connect to my Ubuntu the is expected to function without any display attached to it. The client computer is a Windows 10 computer.

When a TV monitor is attached to the Ubuntu, TeamViewer works just fine. When the TV monitor is disconnected from Ubuntu, TeamViewer displays a black screen when a connection is made.

I know this question is better suited for TeamViewer, but since there seems to be a problem with their website I thought I post it here just in case someone else has experienced the issue and knows a way about it.

Thanks

Farzad

Comment: I think it's supposed to have *some* display, either physical or virtual or this: https://superuser.com/a/864065/931000